# What's the difference between a const member function and a non-const member function?

Tags: c++

I am very confused about the const version and non-const version member function like below:

```
value_type& top() { return this.item }
const value_type& top() const { return this.item }
```

What is the difference between these two functions? In what situation would they be used?

Comment: You should consider getting one of the excellent introductory books listed in [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Nitpick: `mutable` is a C++ keyword with its own meaning and is not simply the opposite of `const`.  Your question would be more clearly phrased as "What's the difference between a const member function and a non-const member function?"

Comment: @Josh - good point about explicit disambiguation, but I think 'mutable' is common enough description, in programming languages, of 'something you can modify'.

Comment: @Josh: I agree and have updated the question accordingly. If anyone is offended by this, feel free to rollback :)

Comment: @Josh: You are right. mutable is not so precise as non-const

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In short, they're used to add 'const correctness' to your program.

```
value_type& top() { return this.item }
```

This is used to provide mutable access to `item`.  It is used so you can modify the element in the container.

For example:

```
c.top().set_property(5);  // OK - sets a property of 'item'
cout << c.top().get_property();  // OK - gets a property of 'item'
```

One common example for this pattern is returning mutable access to an element with `vector::operator[int index]`.

```
std::vector<int> v(5);
v[0] = 1;  // Returns operator[] returns int&.
```

On the other hand:

```
const value_type& top() const { return this.item }
```

This is used to provide `const` access to `item`.  It's more restrictive than the previous version - but it has one advantage - you can call it on a const object.

```
void Foo(const Container &c) {
   c.top();  // Since 'c' is const, you cannot modify it... so the const top is called.
   c.top().set_property(5);  // compile error can't modify const 'item'.
   c.top().get_property();   // OK, const access on 'item'. 
}
```

To follow the vector example:

```
const std::vector<int> v(5, 2);
v[0] = 5;  // compile error, can't mutate a const vector.
std::cout << v[1];  // OK, const access to the vector.
```

Answer (score 6):

The const-qualified member function will be called if the member function is called on an object that is const-qualified.

The non-const-qualified member function will be called if the member function is called on an object that is not const-qualified.

For example:

```
MyStack s;
s.top(); // calls non-const member function

const MyStack t;
t.top(); // calls const member function
```

Note that the same rules apply when calling a member function on a reference to an object or through a pointer to an object:  if the pointer or reference is to a const object, the const member function will be called; otherwise the non-const member function will be called.

Comment: If there is a memeber function like value_type& top() const { return this.item }, can a non-const object call it? If add const like function foo() const, it means that it would change the current object, is it right? If so, it should be called by non-const or const object. Is it right?

Comment: If an object is not const and there are both const and non-const overloads of a member function (and those overloads are otherwise the same), then the non-const member function will be called.  You can "force" the const member function to be called by casting the object to a const reference and then calling the member function on that.  A const member function cannot modify any non-mutable members of the object nor can it call any non-const member functions.

Comment: @Yongwei Xing, to add to James's response, if you give only a "const" overload, it will be used by both const and non-const objects. It's only if you have both a const and non-const overload, where they will use different versions. In general, if something can be declared "const", then it should be... non-const objects can invoke both const and non-const functions, while const objects can only invoke const-qualified member functions.

Answer (score 4):

If you have

```
class Foo
{
    value_type& top() { return this.item }
    const value_type& top() const { return this.item }
}
```

If you have

```
Foo foo;
const Foo cfoo;
```

The return types when you call `top()` are as follows:

```
value_type& bar = foo.top();
const value_type& cbar = cfoo.top();
```

In other words - if you have a constant instance of your class, the const version of the function is chosen as the overload to call.

The reason for this (in this particular case) is so that you can give out references to members (like `item` in this case) from a const instance of a class, and ensure that they too are const - thus unmodifiable and therefore preserving the const-ness of the instance they came from.

Answer (score 0):

When member function is declared as `const` what's happening is that the implicit `this` pointer parameter passed to the function is typed to be a pointer to a const object.  This allows the function to be called using a const object instance.

```
value_type& top();    // this function cannot be called using a `const` object
const value_type& top() const; // this function can be called on a `const` object
```

Answer (score 0):

`value_type& top() { return this.item; }` ensures that either the calling object's data members can be modified or the return value can be.

`value_type& top() const { return this.item; }` ensures that the calling object's data members can't be modified, but the return value can be. So, for example, if I perform `value_type item_of_x = x.top();`, `item_of_x` can be modified but `x` cannot. Otherwise, a compiler error occurs (such as having the code `this.item = someValue;` inside of the function body).

`const value_type& top() { return this.item; }` ensures that the calling object's data members are allowed to be modified, but the return value cannot be. It's the opposite of what is discussed above: if I perform `const value_type item_of_x = x.top();`, `item_of_x` can't be modified but `x` can. **NOTE** `value_type item_of_x = x.top();` still allows for modification of `item_of_x`, as `item_of_x` is now non-const.

`const value_type& top() const { return this.item; }` ensures that neither the calling object's data members can be modified nor the return value can be.