# Why is const required [C++]?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between a const member function and a non-const member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066863/whats-the-difference-between-a-const-member-function-and-a-non-const-member-func)

```
    class Message
{
    public:
        Message(const char* pStr, const char* key);
        Message(const char* pStr);
        Message();

        void encryptMessage();
        void decryptMessage();

        const char* getUnMessage() const;
        const char* getEnMessage() const;

        void getMessage();
        void getKey();

        ~Message();

    private:
        char* pUnMessage;
        char* pEnMessage;
        char* pKey;
};
```

In this program, why using const? (2 different places) Please explain those 2 for me.
Thank you very much!

Comment: No...semester already end,, where is homework...Uncle Martin..I just study more by myself...

Comment: "Uncle Martin" :-D

Comment: The only correct Uncle Martin is actually Uncle Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> const char* getUnMessage() **const**;

Indicates that `getUnMessage(`) may be invoked for an instance of the class that is const. It doesn't have any effect on the const-ness of the return value.

> **const** char* getUnMessage() const;

...indicates that the value being returned from `getUnMessage()` is const (and says nothing about the const-ness of the object having its member function called.)

Comment: Try "may be invoked for any instance of the class, even if it is const".  If you don't specify `const`, it can't be called through a const instance, but when you do, it can be called for both const and non-const class instances.

Answer (score 1):

const is used in C++ for a lot of things. Typically to declare that a method doesn't actually modify the state of an object, or to declare that a pointer cannot be modified, or to declare that a *value* cannot be modified, or both.

For further reading, I suggest the following:

http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html