# Need understanding of question regarding Const Function in C++

Tags: c++

Regarding my understanding of this question:

> ### Question # 03:
>
> - Take any class from your course project. "Each member should have different class from their project".
> - Make one of its int data member constant.
> - Create 4 functions to see the use of Constant keyword. Each function should return the modified integer (**not void**).
>
> | **Function Name** | **Data to be modified** | **Function Type** |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | *Int NonConstant( int x)* | Non-Constant | Non-Constant |
> | *Int ConstantData( int x)* | Constant | Non-Constant |
> | *Int NonFunction( int x)* | Non-Constant | Constant |
> | *Int ConstantBoth( int x)* | Constant | Constant |

I'm not asking anyone to do this for me, I just want to understand what the question is really trying to say, as I'm getting so many errors in my code if I try to apply changes as shown in the figure.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Project
{
    private:
        
        int const x;
        int y;
        
    public:
        
        Project():x(5){}

        int NonConstant(int const x){
            this->y=x;
            return y;
        }
        
        int ConstData(const int x)
            return x;
        }
//      
//      const int ConstFunction(int x){
//              x++;
//              return x;
//      }
//        const void ConstBoth(void) const {
//          x++;
//      }
};


int main()
{
    Project obj;
    cout<<"NonConstant(1): "<<obj.NonConstant(1)<<endl;
    cout<<"ConstData(1): "<<obj.ConstData(1)<<endl;
    cout<<"ConstFunction(1): "<<obj.ConstFunction(1)<<endl;
//  obj.ConstBoth();
}
```

Comment: `int const x` and `const int x` are exactly the same.

Comment: Whoever wrote that question could've done a lot better in writing that question.

Comment: Also, returning a `const` value has no real meaning. The caller could still assign the returned value to a non-const variable. And returning `const void` means even less, since nothing is even returned.

Comment: @AnoopRana  absolutely man.

Comment: And a `const` qualified function (like `void ConstBoth() const`) can't modify member variables. Not that it matters in your specific case, as `const` member variables can't be modified anyway.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes brother i know that, const member variables, cant be modified and const object variables can be be modified using mutable keyword.

Comment: just want people opinions and solutions

Comment: "want to understand what question is really trying to say": Looks like you'll have to ask the instructor or assistant, etc., because I have to guess at a lot of parts, and have no clue in particular what the "Function Type" column is about. And it sounds like the other commenters also don't know.

Comment: My guess would be the "data to be modified" column refers to the parameter being (non-)`const` while the "function type" column refers to it being a (non-)`const` member function. Although it is strange that the first column explicitly shows the parameter as non-const every time

Comment: @perivesta   

class Project
{
 private:
  
  int const x;
  int y;
  
 public:
  
  Project():x(5){}

  int NonConstant(int x){
   return x;
  }
  
  int ConstData(int const x){
   return x;
  } 
  
  const int ConstFunction(int x){
   return x;
  }
  const ConstBoth(const int x){
   return x;
  }
};


int main()
{
 Project obj;
 cout<<"NonConstant(1): "<<obj.NonConstant(1)<<endl;
 cout<<"ConstData(1): "<<obj.ConstData(1)<<endl;
 cout<<"ConstFunction(1): "<<obj.ConstFunction(1)<<endl;
 cout<<"ConstBoth(1): "<<obj.ConstBoth(1);
}

Comment: Also note that the constness of the arguments means the compiler can't use move semantic. This questions seems to be from a time before there was move semantic in C++ as it's awfully incomplete in modern c++. There are a lot more cases to consider today.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?
I had to rewrite your last function because it violated the principle of constant functions.

**Edit:** modified the functions according to *Question #3*.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Project
{
private:

    int const x;
    int y;

public:

    Project():x(5) {}

    // Non-constant data & function
    int NonConstant(int a)
    {
        this->y = a;
        return y;
    }

    // Constant data & Non-constant function
    int ConstData(const int a)
    {
        //a++; // You cannot modify const variables
        return a;
    }

    // Non-constant data & Constant function
    int ConstFunction(int a) const
    {
        a++;
        return a;
    }

    int ConstBoth(const int a) const
    {
        //a++; // You cannot modify const variables
        return a;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Project obj;
    cout<<"NonConstant(1): "<<obj.NonConstant(1)<<endl;
    cout<<"ConstData(1): "<<obj.ConstData(1)<<endl;
    cout<<"ConstFunction(1): "<<obj.ConstFunction(1)<<endl;
    cout<<"ConstBoth(1): "<<obj.ConstBoth(1)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Let's hope its not what OP needs because `const int ConstFunction(int x)`  is nonsensical amongst many other things.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I agree that the return value should be just int in all cases, but it seems that he/she just wants to experiment.

Comment: I'd imagine `ConstFunction` is supposed to be `int ConstFunction(int x) const {`, to denote a function which does not modify the current object nor its fields.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say there is a struct with two members `c` and `x`:

```
struct S{
    // This is already quite unusual.
    // Nobody can change c after creation.
    // Because of constness.
       const int c = 42;   // Good useful number

    // x is part of the objects state.
    // x is important to protect for some reason or other.
    // Lets make it private:
    private:
       int x; 
    public:
    // Now how can others access x. 
    // In a non const way
    int& get_x_non();
    // Or in a const way 1 (A copy of out const):
    int get_x() const;
    // Or in a const way 2 (Our actual x as const, don't use with 1):
    const int& get_x() const;
    // The const after the function is part of the functions cv-qualifiers.
    // And makes a promise to the caller user that the object
    // doesn't change if get_x() is called.
    
    // So lets try to make a member function change c.
    void set_c(int new_c){
        // The compiler will not let this happen.
        c = new_c; 
    }
}
```

So:

```
void f(){
    S s;
    s.get_x_non() = 43; // Ok!
    s.get_x() = 44 // Can't happen
    int i = s.get_x(); // Always works.
    int j = s.c;  // Always works
    // neither i or j is const.
}
```

As you may notice, I can't really correlate these typical
`const` scenarios to the questions in your assignment, that's
why @Anoop's comment got a lot of cheering on.

As a consequence, we are going to have a hard time helping you with this particular problem. You need to ask whatever teaching staff you have available.

You can read more here: [What's the difference between a const member function and a non-const member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066863/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks that is an improvement.